# AJAX request to Flickr API returns 0 results, but works with curl/postman

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, flickr

I'm building a single page web app which makes an AJAX request to Flickr (using the Flickr API).  When I try the request using curl or postman it works.  When I try it from Chrome using AJAX (jQuery), I get a 200 response back with a status of "OK", but always 0 results.  If I take the exact same URL (literally copy and paste) into postman/curl I get results.  I must be doing something dumb but I can't figure it out.

JavaScript Code:

```
var photoQueryURL = 'https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?' + $.param({
    'method': 'flickr.photos.search',
    'api_key': flickrAPIKey,
    'text': title,
    'tags': title,
    'format': 'json',
    'nojsoncallback': '1'
});
// AJAX Query:
$.ajax(photoQueryURL)
    .done(function(data) {
        console.log('Sucessful query.');
        console.log(data);
    })
    .fail(function(err) {
        console.log('Failed query.');
        console.log(err);
    });
```

AJAX Query:

```
Request URL:https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=<my-key>&text=Alex%27s%20Pizzeria&tags=Alex%27s%20Pizzeria&format=json&nojsoncallback=1
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 
Remote Address:69.147.64.33:443
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
Response Headers
access-control-allow-origin:*
age:2
cache-control:private
content-encoding:gzip
content-length:83
content-type:application/json
date:Sat, 28 Oct 2017 21:59:02 GMT
p3p:policyref="https://policies.yahoo.com/w3c/p3p.xml", CP="CAO DSP COR CUR ADM DEV TAI PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi TELo OTPi OUR DELi SAMi OTRi UNRi PUBi IND PHY ONL UNI PUR FIN COM NAV INT DEM CNT STA POL HEA PRE LOC GOV"
server:ATS
status:200
vary:Accept-Encoding
via:http/1.1 fts126.flickr.bf1.yahoo.com (ApacheTrafficServer [cMsSf ]), http/1.1 e22.ycpi.cha.yahoo.com (ApacheTrafficServer [cMsSf ])
x-content-type-options:nosniff
x-frame-options:SAMEORIGIN
x-served-by:www-bm006.flickr.bf1.yahoo.com
Request Headers
:authority:api.flickr.com
:method:GET
:path:/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=<my-key>&text=Alex%27s%20Pizzeria&tags=Alex%27s%20Pizzeria&format=json&nojsoncallback=1
:scheme:https
accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
accept-encoding:gzip, deflate, br
accept-language:en-US,en;q=0.9
cache-control:no-cache
origin:null
pragma:no-cache
user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.75 Safari/537.36
Query String Parameters
view source
view URL encoded
method:flickr.photos.search
api_key:<my-key>
text:Alex's Pizzeria
tags:Alex's Pizzeria
format:json
nojsoncallback:1
```

AJAX Response:

```
{"photos":{"page":1,"pages":0,"perpage":100,"total":"0","photo":[]},"stat":"ok"}
```

Query with curl:

```
curl -k "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=<my-key>&text=Alex%27s%20Pizza&tags=Alex%27s%20Pizza&format=json&nojsoncallback=1"
```

Response (notice 5 results):

```
{"photos": {"page": 1, "pages": 1, "perpage": 100, "total": "5",
"photo": [{"id":(...)}]},
"stat":"ok"}
```

Suggestions?

--Jim

Comment: Can you share the `JSON` response object that you get? In Google Chrome press F12, network tab / XHR.

Comment: May be the photos isn't shared :).

Comment: @Danny, Sure - I edited the main thread.  Is that what you wanted?

Comment: @headmax - good question, this query is not for a specific photo.  Rather it's a photo search.  Also, if I take the exact same URL and paste it into postman/curl, I get results on the query shown.

Comment: I see that the `"photo":[]` key hasn't results. So, `0 results` you'll get.

Comment: ok so can i suggest an other way api ajax call but no guaranty if you got a json with datas.

Comment: @Danny - here's the Flickr API I'm using:  https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.html, it also has an API Explorer.  According to that I am using the API correctly - if I take this exact query and use Flickr's API explorer it works (produces results).  So the query isn't the problem.  It's something I'm doing with the JavaScript code.

Comment: @headmax - sure if there's another way to do this I'd be happy to try.

Comment: In your jQuery code, you should have results when you do: `console.log(data.photo);`.

Comment: @Danny - See how in my question the AJAX request gets a response of: "total":"0" and the same request from curl gets a response of: "total":"5".  The requests appear to be identical and yet curl gets 5 results and using AJAX from Chrome gets 0.  Why is this?

Comment: @JamesS. I gotten boths way in my 2 posts examples, so i think your ajax got a problem but i didn't see with my bad eyes or i am tired i dunno ...

Comment: @headmax - I agree with you.  I'm definitely doing something wrong in my AJAX request, I just can't figure it out...

Comment: @JamesS. i guess copy/paste isn't a crime ;).

Comment: I'm going to reproduce your issue in my demo site. I'll let you know.

Comment: @JamesS. Can you see my answer?

Comment: @JamesS. i think you don't see but this url give me an error about CORS no allowed ...

Comment: @headmax - I think you're right, it's something with CORS.  That would explain why it's different in the browser.  Looking at that now - I suppose I can always switch to JSONP...

Comment: @JamesS. you can avoid this by many ways :) i am on i got a payload but now i try other thing if i can ;).

Comment: OK - final update, it's not a CORS issue and it pretty much works as is.  There are a couple of instances where I seem to get different results depending on where I query from.  I'm not sure about that, but calling it good.  Thanks for everyone's help with this.  I think much of the problem is I'm still getting my head around async programming in JavaScript and how promises work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct. I've made a Flickr Account to reproduce your issue.

I added this code to print the results:

```
var len = data.photos.photo.length, html = "";
if (len > 0) {
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    html += "<li>";
    html += data.photos.photo[i].title;
    html += "</li>";
  }
  $("#list").html(html);
}
```

Something like this:

```js
(function() {
  $("#form").on("submit", function(e) {
    var flickrAPIKey = "39417c145483a7fb3ee91c5fe5bc93fe",
      title = $("#txtInput").val();
    var photoQueryURL = 'https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?' + $.param({
      'method': 'flickr.photos.search',
      'api_key': flickrAPIKey,
      'text': title,
      'tags': title,
      'format': 'json',
      'nojsoncallback': '1'
    });
    // AJAX Query:
    $.ajax(photoQueryURL)
      .done(function(data) {
        console.log('Sucessful query.');
        var len = data.photos.photo.length, html = "";
        if (len > 0) {
          var i;
          for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            html += "<li>";
            html += data.photos.photo[i].title;
            html += "</li>";
          }
          $("#list").html(html);
        }
      })
      .fail(function(err) {
        console.log('Failed query.');
        console.log(err);
      });
    e.preventDefault();
  });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
  <label for="txtInput">Input:</label>
  <input id="txtInput" type="text" />
  <button type="submit">Send</button>
  <hr />
  <ul id="list"></ul>
</form>
```

The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header is present.

[image]

Comment: Fardy Jhonston Bermùdez same for me. To avoid this he need to crapping datas using fetch or curl or bypassing methods for a paylods ... and been in CORS wave.

Comment: @Danny - you're right, if I try different queries I can get some to succeed.  So I guess what I don't understand is why I get different results if I use Flickr's API explorer (or postman or curl) vs. using Chrome and AJAX.  I will open a separate question for that - thanks.

Comment: @Danny - you're right, the code is correct.  Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  //store public feed in URL
  var URL = "https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?";
  //create searchInfo object
  var searchInfo = {
    
    tags : $('#searchfield').val(),
    tagmode : "any",
    format : "json"
  };
  //when search button is clicked
  $('#searchbtn').click(function(){
    //update the search info object
    searchInfo.tags = $('#searchfield').val();
    //get JSON
    $.getJSON(URL,searchInfo,function(data){
        var photoHTML = '';
        //loop through each photo object
        $.each(data.items, function(i, photo) {
          photoHTML += '<span class ="image">';
          photoHTML += '<a href="' + photo.link 
                        + '">';
          photoHTML += '<img src ="' +         photo.media.m.replace('_m','_s')+'"></a></span>';
         
       });// end each
     
      //add the HTML to the page
     $('#images').append(photoHTML);
       
      
    }); // end get JSON
    
  }); //end click
  
}); //end ready
```

```css
.image {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 30px 30px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Flickr Search for example kitten :)</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Flickr Search</h1>
    <h4>Search for any image here!</h4>
    <input type="text" id="searchfield" />
    <button id ="searchbtn">Search</button>
    
    <div id="images">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried this out.  This appears to search for recent adds on Flickr.  However, I want to search all of Flickr.  Check it out - this is the API Explorer for what I want to do.  You can put data in any of the fields you want to use and it will show you the results:  https://www.flickr.com/services/api/explore/flickr.photos.search

Answer (score 0):

```js
/*

  Create an api to get an API KEY here:
  https://www.flickr.com/services/apps/create/

  Documentation for searching photos:
  https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.html

  */

  $('.fetch-button').click(function() {
    var $button = $(this);
    var photoUrl;

    $button.text('Loading...'); // Set text of button to loading
    $button.attr('disabled', 'disabled'); // Disable button
    $('.output').empty(); // Clear out results
    
    //what you are looking for
    var lookingfor = $('#wording').prop('value');
    var perpage = $('#per_page').prop('value');
    var page = $('#page').prop('value');
    var lowlang = $('#lang').prop('value');
    var lang = lowlang.toLowerCase() + '-' + $('#lang').prop('value');
    var api_key = 'e0246bb8460f3650cef44a21d89d4c60';
    var sort = $('#sort').prop('value');
    var content_type = $('#content_type').prop('value');
    
    
    
    console.log(lang)
    
    $.ajax({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'https://api.flickr.com/services/rest?sort=' + sort + '&parse_tags=1&content_type=' + content_type + '&extras=can_comment,count_comments,count_faves,description,isfavorite,license,media,needs_interstitial,owner_name,path_alias,realname,rotation,url_c,url_l,url_m,url_n,url_q,url_s,url_sq,url_t,url_z&per_page=' + perpage + '&page=' + page + '&lang=' + lang + '&text=' + lookingfor + '&viewerNSID=&method=flickr.photos.search&csrf=&api_key=' + api_key + '&format=json&hermes=1&hermesClient=1&reqId=e626c8a6&nojsoncallback=1'
    }).done(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      if (!data.photos) {
        return;
      }
      $.each(data.photos.photo, function(key, photo) {
        photoUrl = 'https://farm' +
          photo.farm +
          '.staticflickr.com/' +
          photo.server +
          '/' +
          photo.id +
          '_' +
          photo.secret +
          '_q.jpg';
        $('.output').append('<img src="' + photoUrl + '">');
      });

    }).always(function() {
      $button.text('Fetch Data'); // Reset button text
      $button.removeAttr('disabled'); // Enable button to be clicked again
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>Flickr API own by fetching all call rest api</h1>
  <input placeholder="search" id="wording" type="text" value="" name="search"/>
  <input placeholder="user_id" id="user_id" type="text" value="" name="user_id"/>
  <input placeholder="tags" id="tags" type="text" value="" name="tags"/>
  <input placeholder="tag_mode" id="tag_mode" type="text" value="" name="tag_mode"/>
  <input placeholder="text" id="text" type="text" value="" name="text"/>
  <input placeholder="min_upload_date" id="min_upload_date" type="text" value="" name="min_upload_date"/>
  <input placeholder="max_upload_date" id="max_upload_date" type="text" value="" name="max_upload_date"/>
  <input placeholder="min_taken_date" id="min_taken_date" type="text" value="" name="min_taken_date"/>
  <input placeholder="max_taken_date" id="max_taken_date" type="text" value="" name="max_taken_date"/>
  <input placeholder="license" id="license" type="text" value="" name="license"/>
  <input placeholder="sort" id="sort" type="text" value="relevance" name="sort"/>
  <input placeholder="privacy_filter" id="privacy_filter" type="text" value="" name="privacy_filter"/>
  <input placeholder="bbox" id="bbox" type="text" value="" name="bbox"/>
  <input placeholder="accuracy" id="accuracy" type="text" value="" name="accuracy"/>
  <input placeholder="safe_search" id="safe_search" type="text" value="" name="safe_search"/>
  <input placeholder="content_type" id="content_type" type="text" value="7" name="content_type"/>
  <input placeholder="machine_tags" id="machine_tags" type="text" value="" name="machine_tags"/>
  <input placeholder="machine_tag_mode" id="machine_tag_mode" type="text" value="" name="machine_tag_mode"/>
  <input placeholder="group_id" id="group_id" type="text" value="" name="group_id"/>
  <input placeholder="contacts" id="contacts" type="text" value="" name="contacts"/>
  <input placeholder="woe_id" id="woe_id" type="text" value="" name="woe_id"/>
  <input placeholder="place_id" id="place_id" type="text" value="" name="place_id"/>
  <input placeholder="media" id="media" type="text" value="" name="media"/>
  <input placeholder="has_geo" id="has_geo" type="text" value="" name="has_geo"/>
  <input placeholder="geo_context" id="geo_context" type="text" value="" name="geo_context"/>
  <input placeholder="lat" id="lat" type="text" value="" name="lat"/>
  <input placeholder="lon" id="lon" type="text" value="" name="lon"/>
  <input placeholder="radius" id="radius" type="text" value="" name="radius"/>
  <input placeholder="radius_units" id="radius_units" type="text" value="" name="radius_units"/>
  <input placeholder="is_commons" id="is_commons" type="text" value="" name="is_commons"/>
  <input placeholder="in_gallery" id="in_gallery" type="text" value="" name="in_gallery"/>
  <input placeholder="is_getty" id="is_getty" type="text" value="" name="is_getty"/>
  <input placeholder="extras" id="extras" type="text" value="" name="extras"/>
  <input placeholder="per_page" id="per_page" type="text" value="25" name="per_page"/>
  <input placeholder="page" id="page" type="text" value="1" name="page"/>
  <select id="lang" name="lang" data-placeholder="Choose a Language...">
  <option value="AF">Afrikanns</option>
  <option value="SQ">Albanian</option>
  <option value="AR">Arabic</option>
  <option value="HY">Armenian</option>
  <option value="EU">Basque</option>
  <option value="BN">Bengali</option>
  <option value="BG">Bulgarian</option>
  <option value="CA">Catalan</option>
  <option value="KM">Cambodian</option>
  <option value="ZH">Chinese (Mandarin)</option>
  <option value="HR">Croation</option>
  <option value="CS">Czech</option>
  <option value="DA">Danish</option>
  <option value="NL">Dutch</option>
  <option value="EN" selected>English</option>
  <option value="ET">Estonian</option>
  <option value="FJ">Fiji</option>
  <option value="FI">Finnish</option>
  <option value="FR">French</option>
  <option value="KA">Georgian</option>
  <option value="DE">German</option>
  <option value="EL">Greek</option>
  <option value="GU">Gujarati</option>
  <option value="HE">Hebrew</option>
  <option value="HI">Hindi</option>
  <option value="HU">Hungarian</option>
  <option value="IS">Icelandic</option>
  <option value="ID">Indonesian</option>
  <option value="GA">Irish</option>
  <option value="IT">Italian</option>
  <option value="JA">Japanese</option>
  <option value="JW">Javanese</option>
  <option value="KO">Korean</option>
  <option value="LA">Latin</option>
  <option value="LV">Latvian</option>
  <option value="LT">Lithuanian</option>
  <option value="MK">Macedonian</option>
  <option value="MS">Malay</option>
  <option value="ML">Malayalam</option>
  <option value="MT">Maltese</option>
  <option value="MI">Maori</option>
  <option value="MR">Marathi</option>
  <option value="MN">Mongolian</option>
  <option value="NE">Nepali</option>
  <option value="NO">Norwegian</option>
  <option value="FA">Persian</option>
  <option value="PL">Polish</option>
  <option value="PT">Portuguese</option>
  <option value="PA">Punjabi</option>
  <option value="QU">Quechua</option>
  <option value="RO">Romanian</option>
  <option value="RU">Russian</option>
  <option value="SM">Samoan</option>
  <option value="SR">Serbian</option>
  <option value="SK">Slovak</option>
  <option value="SL">Slovenian</option>
  <option value="ES">Spanish</option>
  <option value="SW">Swahili</option>
  <option value="SV">Swedish </option>
  <option value="TA">Tamil</option>
  <option value="TT">Tatar</option>
  <option value="TE">Telugu</option>
  <option value="TH">Thai</option>
  <option value="BO">Tibetan</option>
  <option value="TO">Tonga</option>
  <option value="TR">Turkish</option>
  <option value="UK">Ukranian</option>
  <option value="UR">Urdu</option>
  <option value="UZ">Uzbek</option>
  <option value="VI">Vietnamese</option>
  <option value="CY">Welsh</option>
  <option value="XH">Xhosa</option>
</select>
 
  
  <button class="fetch-button">Fetch Data</button>
  <div class="output">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @JamesS test it you need to set some other i did for a good part thank you for your contribution. Regards.